# How to type quickly tag img inside tag a in HTML in sublime text?

Tags: html

I see a guy when he type "a>img" and press tab (type on sublime text), the code appears: `<a><img src=""></a>`, but I can't do that, how did he do that? thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install emmet.

The preferred way to install Emmet is to use Package Control:

1. Open Command Palette in Sublime Text
2. Pick “`Install Package`” command
3. Find and install “Emmet” plugin

here you can find :-
https://emmet.io/blog/sublime-text-3/